# How could I speed up data search, in a large volume database (using spring reactive and postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, spring-webflux, reactive-programming, sha, java-17

I am using a database that has **800,000,000**+ ***hashes***. This database needs to be searched.

- the client enters the line
- the string on the server is converted to hash using the SHA-1 algorithm
- then a similar hash is searched for by this value in the table

```sql
SELECT table_source.id
FROM base_source
WHERE table_source.str_source_sha1 =
      '01B3773A12C0ED01767870001574FF002342F7521E';
```

- the index is set for the field for which the search is performed

```sql
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS encoded_index
    ON table_source (str_source_sha1);
```

Search from the console of the client connected to the database (using the client from Intellij Idea):

- searching for a value that is in the database (id = 600 735 221) takes time

1 row retrieved starting from 1 in 164 ms (execution: 129 ms, fetching: 35 ms)

- At the same time, the search for the same value is slightly reduced if it is done several times in a row, due to caching (my guess)

- searching for a value that is not in the database takes time

0 rows retrieved in 62 ms (execution: 15 ms, fetching: 47 ms)

Then I wrote code that would filter the loaded elements in the stream

```java
public Mono<Boolean> runCheckupStrInHash(ResultCheckupDto resultCheckupDto) {


    String strInPlainText = resultCheckupDto.getStr();
String shaAlgorithm = encodeToSHAService.generateIntoSHAAlgorithm(strInPlainText);

return sourceRepository.findAll()
            .flatMap(
                    strFromBase -> {
                        boolean isExistsStr = strFromBase.equals(shaAlgorithm);
                        if (isExistsStr) {
                            return Mono.just(Boolean.TRUE);
                        }

                        return Mono.empty();
                    }

            )
            .next()
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(Boolean.FALSE));
}
```

However, this lasts a very long time.

Then I completely decided to assign the search responsibility to the database.

```java
public Mono<Boolean> isExistsStr(ResultCheckupDto resultCheckupDto) {


      long start = System.nanoTime();

return Mono.just(resultCheckupDto)
              .map(resultCheckupDto::getStr)
              .map(encodeToSHAService:: generateIntoSHAAlgorithm)
              .flatMap(sourceRepository::existsByStrEncodedSha)
              .map(result -> {
                  long end = System.nanoTime();
                  long timeProcessing = end - start;

                  double seconds = timeProcessing / 1_000_000_000.0;

                  log.info("\n request processing time (database request) (sek) : {} \n", seconds);
                  return result;
              });
}
```

- first, the string is encoded in a hash using the SHA-1 algorithm
- then a request is made to the database using this hash

```sql
SELECT table_source.id
FROM base_source
WHERE table_source.str_source_sha1 =
      '01B3773A12C0ED01767870001574FF002342F7521E';
```

Request processing time:

- if there is such a value, then the search is more than 110 + seconds
- if there is no value, then the search is more than 160 + seconds

Using redis cache would not be a good option, the database size is 35+ gb, with an index larger.

What do you think about this ?

Who has any ideas how to reduce this response time by more than 10 times?

Comment: for equality queries it is worth considering a `hash index` instead of a `btree`.

Comment: it sounds like progress :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what prompted
**Jim Jones**, I applied hash index.

```sql
/*17 min an index is being created*/
create index idxhash__encoded_index on table_source using hash (encoded_sha1);
```

Now time for processing request is **0.004421041** - **0.063014875** sec.

However, this still needs to be tested on the load bench to make sure that it works as it should.